# use docker for google cloud data flow dependencies

Tags: python, opencv, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I am interested in using Google cloud Dataflow to parallel process videos. My job uses both OpenCV and tensorflow. Is it possible to just run the workers inside a docker instance, rather than installing all the dependencies from source as described:

https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/dependencies-python

I would have expected a flag for a docker container, which is already sitting in google container engine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**2021 update**

Dataflow now supports custom docker containers. You can create your own container by following these instructions:

https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/using-custom-containers

The short answer is that Beam publishes containers under `dockerhub.io/apache/beam_${language}_sdk:${version}`.

In your Dockerfile you would use one of them as base:

```
FROM apache/beam_python3.8_sdk:2.30.0
# Add your customizations and dependencies
```

Then you would upload this image to a container registry like GCR or Dockerhub, and then you would specify the following option: `--worker_harness_container_image=$IMAGE_URI`

And bing! you have a customer container.

---

It is not possible to modify or switch the default Dataflow worker container. You need to install the dependencies according to the documentation.

Comment: That's almost shocking. Do you know why? Installing OpenCV on each worker will take 10 to 15 minutes. Its already compiled and ready to go in docker. Am I using the wrong tool to do parallel processing on google cloud platform?

Comment: We understand this is a pain point, but currently it is not possible. Unfortunately, we can't give an ETA for it either. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a large number of videos you will have to incur the large startup cost regardless. Thus is the nature of Grid Computing in general.

The other side of this is that you could use larger machines under the job than the n1-standard-1 machines, thus amortizing the cost of the download across less machines that could potentially process more videos at once if the processing was coded correctly.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to issue the pip install commands through the setup.py option listed for [Non-Python Dependencies](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/dependencies-python#non-python-dependencies).

Doing this will download the manylinux wheel instead of the source distribution that the requirements file processing will stage.