# Google Cloud Dataflow Dependencies

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I want to use dataflow to process in parallel a bunch of video clips I have stored in google storage.  My processing algorithm has non-python dependencies and is expected to change over development iterations.

---

My preference would be to use a dockerized container with the logic to process the clips, but it appears that custom containers are not supported (in 2017):

[use docker for google cloud data flow dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44683250/use-docker-for-google-cloud-data-flow-dependencies)

Although they may be supported now - since it was being worked on:

[Posthoc connect FFMPEG to opencv-python binary for Google Cloud Dataflow job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45124289/posthoc-connect-ffmpeg-to-opencv-python-binary-for-google-cloud-dataflow-job)

According to this issue a custom docker image may be pulled, but I couldn't find any documentation on how to do it with dataflow.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-6706?focusedCommentId=16773376&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-16773376

Another option might be to use setup.py to install any dependencies as described in this dated example:

https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/how-to-do-distributed-processing-of-landsat-data-in-python

However, when running the example I get an error that there is no module named osgeo.gdal.

For pure python dependencies I have also tried to pass the `--requirements_file` argument, however I still get an error: `Pip install failed for package: -r`

I could find documentation for adding dependencies to apache_beam, but not to dataflow, and it appears the apache_beam instructions do not work, based on my tests of `--requirements_file` and `--setup_file`

Comment: You say you've tried using `--setup_file` and it hasn't worked. Is that right?  We have an example in Beam that relies on it. Can you check it, and see if that helps? https://github.com/apache/beam/tree/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/examples/complete/juliaset

Comment: The landsat example using setup_file didn't work for me.

I tried the juliaset example and it does work!  Thanks!  Problem solved.

Are there any plans to support docker images in the future?

Comment: Docker images will be supported for pipelines using the portability framework. I can't give a great forecast for the timeline, but the plan is to support custom containers, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was answered in the comments, rewriting here for clarity:

In Apache Beam you can modify the setup.py file while will be run once per container on start-up. This file allows you to perform arbitrary commands before the the SDK Harness start to receive commands from the Runner Harness.

A complete [example](https://github.com/apache/beam/tree/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/examples/complete/juliaset) can be found in the Apache Beam repo.

Answer (score 2):

As of 2020, you can use [Dataflow Flex Templates](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/using-flex-templates), which allow you to specify a custom Docker container in which to execute your pipeline.